# Trying to randomize positions of nodes without any overlapping JavaFX

Tags: java

I have created a for loop to add all my nodes to the root although since their locations are random, a bunch of them end up overlapping.

I added a for loop to move a node if it overlaps another although that doesnt really solve the issue since it may just overlap another.

Anyone know a good way to end up with no overlapping nodes?

Here is my code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < citiesText.length; i++) {

citiesText[i] = new Text(cities[i][0]);
citiesText[i].setFont(Font.font("Impact", 40));
citiesText[i].setFill(Color.WHITE);
citiesText[i].setStrokeWidth(2); 
citiesText[i].setStroke(Color.BLACK); 

double height = citiesText[i].getBoundsInParent().getHeight();
double width = citiesText[i].getBoundsInParent().getWidth();
double maxX = 1000 - width;
double maxY = 550 - height;

root.getChildren().add(citiesText[i]);
citiesText[i].relocate(Math.random()*maxX, Math.random()*maxY);

for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) {

if (citiesText[i].getBoundsInParent().intersects(citiesText[j].getBoundsInParent()))
    citiesText[i].relocate(Math.random()*maxX, Math.random()*maxY); 
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You could add a flag and while the flag is true keep looping until there is no overlapping. This might not be the most efficient way to do it but it should work. i.e.

```
boolean overlap = true;
while(overlap){
     overlap = false;
     for (int j = 0; j < citiesText.length; j++) {

         if(citiesText[i].getBoundsInParent().intersects(citiesText[j].getBoundsInParent())){
             citiesText[i].relocate(Math.random()*maxX, Math.random()*maxY); 
             overlap = true;
         }

     }   
}
```

Comment: Worked great! Thanks!